# ¿como puedo hacer un query SQL, que me de el resultado por cada día del mes?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Bueno ahi va de nuevo la pregunta, tengo el siguiente query:

```
SELECT [date] 
      ,[stationNumber]
      ,[stationName]
      ,[stationComercialName]
      ,[productDescription]
      ,[productColor]
      ,[productCode]
      ,[shift]
      ,SUM([quantity]) as litros
      ,SUM([amount]) as importe
FROM [NexusFuel].[dbo].[vwStationFuelSales]
WHERE [date] >='2017-07-01' AND [date] <= '2017-07-31' AND [stationNumber] = 5087
GROUP BY [date]
      ,[stationNumber]
      ,[stationName]
      ,[stationComercialName]
      ,[productDescription]
      ,[productColor]
      ,[productCode]
      ,[shift]
```

esto me arroja el resultado de cada dia del mes hacia abajo en filas, y lo que yo quiero que me lo de en columnas, "CADA DIA DEL MES ES UNA COLUMNA" y ya abajo ponerle las ventas, algo similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Saludos!

Comment: Podrías hacerlo usando reporting services o reportes nativos de windows (.rdlc)

Comment: Ocupo hacerlo con un query SQL para después ponerlo en una tabla PHP HTML

Comment: Samuel, por favor ajunta la estructuras de las tablas a la pregunta y lo que has intentado hasta ahora, también te recomiendo que leas como crear un [mcve]. Como se suele decir aquí: ayúdanos a ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Una disculpa no soy muy bueno explicando, espero esto sea un poco mejor, saludos!

Comment: Hola @SamuelAlmada, no entiendo muy bien la pregunta, la query te devuelve los datos bien, pero tu quieres mostrar esos datos en una columna no? Puedes mostrar la parte del código donde estás añadiendo esos datos a una vista.

Comment: Has una consulta que te devuelva los registros por vendedor, la fecha y el dato que aparece en el cuadro, despues haces un column group por fecha y sale el reporte en report services, no lo veo muy complicado, mira este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913743/how-do-i-group-columns-in-ssrs-on-row-number-within-a-row-group) es una pregunta igual a la tuya pero con otra prespectiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer, es hacer un `SUM()` para cada día del mes que solicitas, algo así:

```
DECLARE @FechaDesde DATETIME
DECLARE @FechaHasta DATETIME

SELECT  @FechaDesde = '2017-07-01'
SELECT  @FechaHasta = '2017-07-31'

SELECT [date] 
      ,[stationNumber]
      ,[stationName]
      ,[stationComercialName]
      ,[productDescription]
      ,[productColor]
      ,[productCode]
      ,[shift]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN [date] = DATEADD(DAY, 0, @FechaDesde) THEN [quantity] ELSE 0 END) as Dia_1
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN [date] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FechaDesde) THEN [quantity] ELSE 0 END) as Dia_2
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN [date] = DATEADD(DAY, 2, @FechaDesde) THEN [quantity] ELSE 0 END) as Dia_3
      ....
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN [date] = DATEADD(DAY, 30, @FechaDesde) THEN [quantity] ELSE 0 END) as Dia_31

    FROM [NexusFuel].[dbo].[vwStationFuelSales]
    WHERE   [date] >= @FechaDesde 
            AND [date] <= FechaHasta 
            AND [stationNumber] = 5087
    GROUP BY [date]
      ,[stationNumber]
      ,[stationName]
      ,[stationComercialName]
      ,[productDescription]
      ,[productColor]
      ,[productCode]
      ,[shift]
```

Usando la condición `CASE WHEN [date] = DATEADD(DAY, 0, @FechaDesde) THEN [quantity] ELSE 0 END` en el `SUM()` logramos sumar únicamente si el registro corresponde al día 1, (sumamos 0 días al la @FechaDesde: '2017-07-01'), tenemos que construir 31 clausulas `SUM` como la anterior, sumando un día cada vez al `DATEADD` , con esto cubrimos hasta el máximo de días que puede tener cualquier mes

Algunos comentarios:

- Reemplace las fecha "duras" por el uso de variables, sino deberías reescribir la consulta cada vez que modifiques los parámetros
- Los meses de menos de 31 días, van a funcionar bien, pero obviamente las columnas adicionales estarán en 0.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno mil gracias por sus respuestas, me fueron de mucha ayuda, ya solucione mi problema y se los comparto:

```
`DECLARE @columns varchar(MAX);
 DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

 DECLARE @FechaDesde DATETIME
 DECLARE @FechaHasta DATETIME

 SELECT  @FechaDesde = '2017-08-01'
 SELECT  @FechaHasta = '2017-08-31'

 SET @columns = STUFF(
 (
 SELECT
 ',' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM([date]))
 FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT [date]
 FROM [NexusFuel].[dbo].[vwStationFuelSales]
 ) AS T
 WHERE [date] >= @FechaDesde 
 AND [date] <= @FechaHasta 
 ORDER BY
 [date]
 FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, '');

SET @sql = N'
SELECT
* 
FROM
(  
SELECT  [stationComercialName], [productDescription], [quantity], [date]
FROM [NexusFuel].[dbo].[vwStationFuelSales]
) AS T
PIVOT   
(
SUM([quantity])
FOR [date] IN (' + @columns + N')
) AS P order by [stationComercialName];'; 

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;`
```

Lo mejor que se puede hacer es un PIVOT.

Saludos y Gracias!